# Python construct a matrix iterating over arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
from numpy import genfromtxt, linalg, array, append, hstack, vstack

#Euclidean distance function
def euclidean(v1, v2):
    dist = linalg.norm(v1 - v2)
    return dist

#get the .csv files and eliminate heading and unused columns from test
BMUs = genfromtxt('BMU3.csv', delimiter=',')
data = genfromtxt('test.csv', delimiter=',')
data = data[1:, :-2]

i = 0
for obj in data:
    D = 0
    for BMU in BMUs:
        Dist = append(euclidean(obj, BMU[: -2]), BMU[-2:])
    D = hstack(Dist)

Map = vstack(D)

#iteration counter
i += 1
if not i % 1000:
    print (i, ' of ', len(data))

print (Map)
```

What I would like to do is:

1. Take an object from data
2. Calculate distance from BMU (euclidean(obj, BMU[: -2])
3. Append to the distance the last two items of the BMU array
4. create a 2d matrix that contains all the distances plus the last two items of all the BMU from a data object (D = hstack(Dist))
5. create an array of those matrices with length equal to the number of objects in data. (Map = vstack(D))

The problem here, or at least what I think is the problem, is that hstack and vstack would like as input a tuple of an array and not a single array. It's like I'm trying to use them as I use List.append() for lists, sadly I'm a beginner and I have no idea how to do it differently.

Any help would be awesome, thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a usage note:

Instead of:

```
from numpy import genfromtxt, linalg, array, append, hstack, vstack
```

use

```
import numpy as np
....
data = np.genfromtxt(....)
....
     np.hstack...
```

Secondly, stay away from `np.append`.  It too easy to misuse.  Use `np.concatenate` so you get the full flavor of what it is doing.

list `append` is better for incremental work

```
alist = []
for ....
    alist.append(....)
arr = np.array(alist)
```

==================

Without sample arrays (or at least shapes) I'm guessing.  But (n,2) arrays sound reasonable.  Taking the distance of each pair of 'points' from each other, I can collect the values in a nested list comprehension:

```
In [121]: data = np.arange(6).reshape(3,2)
In [122]: [[euclidean(d,b) for b in data] for d in data]
Out[122]: 
[[0.0, 2.8284271247461903, 5.6568542494923806],
 [2.8284271247461903, 0.0, 2.8284271247461903],
 [5.6568542494923806, 2.8284271247461903, 0.0]]
```

and make that an array:

```
In [123]: np.array([[euclidean(d,b) for b in data] for d in data])
Out[123]: 
array([[ 0.        ,  2.82842712,  5.65685425],
       [ 2.82842712,  0.        ,  2.82842712],
       [ 5.65685425,  2.82842712,  0.        ]])
```

The equivalent with nested loops:

```
alist = []
for d in data:
    sublist=[]
    for b in data:
        sublist.append(euclidean(d,b))
    alist.append(sublist)
arr = np.array(alist)
```

There are ways of doing this without loops, but let's make sure the basic Python looping approach works first.

===============

If I want the difference (along the last axis) between every element (row) in `data` and every element in `bmu` (or here `data`), I can use array broadcasting.  The result is a (3,3,2) array:

```
In [130]: data[None,:,:]-data[:,None,:]
Out[130]: 
array([[[ 0,  0],
        [ 2,  2],
        [ 4,  4]],

       [[-2, -2],
        [ 0,  0],
        [ 2,  2]],

       [[-4, -4],
        [-2, -2],
        [ 0,  0]]])
```

`norm` can handle larger dimensional arrays and takes an `axis` parameter.

```
In [132]: np.linalg.norm(data[None,:,:]-data[:,None,:],axis=-1)
Out[132]: 
array([[ 0.        ,  2.82842712,  5.65685425],
       [ 2.82842712,  0.        ,  2.82842712],
       [ 5.65685425,  2.82842712,  0.        ]])
```

Comment: Thank you very much, will be waiting for your advice :)

Comment: What's the `shape` (and `dtype`) for `BMU` and `data`?  It's easier to replicate and test your code with samples.  Otherwise I have to guess and make up sample arrays (like `data=np.arange(24).reshape(12,2)`).

Comment: (243, 7) BMUs.shape 

(19219, 5) data.shape

Comment: Type: they are both numpy arrays

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your help, I managed to implement the pseudo code, here the final program:

```
import numpy as np


def euclidean(v1, v2):
    dist = np.linalg.norm(v1 - v2)
    return dist


def makeKNN(dataSet, BMUSet, k, fileOut, test=False):
    # take input files
    BMUs = np.genfromtxt(BMUSet, delimiter=',')
    data = np.genfromtxt(dataSet, delimiter=',')

    final = data[1:, :]
    if test == False:
        data = data[1:, :]
    else:
        data = data[1:, :-2]

# Calculate all the distances between data and BMUs than reorder BMU with the distances information

    dist = np.array([[euclidean(d, b[:-2]) for b in BMUs] for d in data])
    BMU_K = np.array([BMUs[np.argsort(d)] for d in dist])

    # median over the closest k BMU
    Z = np.array([[np.sum(b[:k].T[5]) / k] for b in BMU_K])

    # error propagation
    Z_err = np.array([[np.sqrt(np.sum(np.power(b[:k].T[5], 2)))] for b in BMU_K])

    # Adding z estimates and errors to the data
    final = np.concatenate((final, Z, Z_err), axis=1)

    # print output file
    np.savetxt(fileOut, final, delimiter=',')
    print('So long, and thanks for all the fish')
```

Thank you very much and I hope that this code will help someone else in the future :)